# Prevent console window from being created in custom node.js build

Tags: windows, node.js, winapi

I'm creating a custom build of node.js that should not show a console window to the user.

I've tried changing the [linker config in the gyp file](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.10.26/node.gyp#L302) to `2` (which should set the linker [flag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fcc1zstk.aspx) `/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS`), but I still get a console window when I run the resulting node.exe binary.

How can I prevent the console window from appearing?

---

**Edit:** Further investigation reveals that the linker config in node.gyp is not taking effect.  The generated node.vcxproj still has `<Link><SubSystem>Console</SubSystem></Link>` (which is very strange to me, since adding `'UACUIAccess': 'true'` in the same part of node.gyp did take effect), so the built binary is incorrectly linked.

Comment: My guess is that you're going to need to make a shortcut which starts the window minimized. If you want better then you'll need to write a launcher in an application language which doesn't use the console window. I'd use an C application to do this.

Comment: Starting the console minimized won't work for me, nor will a launcher.  I'm hacking on a fork of node, so I have full control of the code (JS and C).

Comment: Write a small app to launch it using CreateProcess: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you must:

- Comment out the `'SubSystem': 1` line in [common.gypi](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.10.26/common.gypi#L151).  (Changing it to `2` causes the build to fail in mksnapshot.)
- Change `SubSystem` to `2` in [node.gyp](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.10.26/node.gyp#L302)
- Also add `'EntryPointSymbol': 'wmainCRTStartup'` to node.gyp.

This builds a node.exe that does not create a console window.

Answer (score 2):

**Solution 1**

Save this one line of text as file invisible.vbs:

```
CreateObject(“Wscript.Shell”).Run “”"” & WScript.Arguments(0) & “”"”, 0, False
```

To run any program or batch file invisibly, use it like this:

```
wscript.exe “C:\Wherever\invisible.vbs” “C:\Some Other Place\MyBatchFile.bat”
```

To also be able to pass-on/relay a list of arguments use only two double quotes

```
CreateObject(“Wscript.Shell”).Run “” & WScript.Arguments(0) & “”, 0, False
```

eg: `Invisible.vbs “Kill.vbs ME.exe”`

**Solution 2**

Use a command line tool to silently launch a process : [Quiet](http://www.joeware.net/freetools/tools/quiet/index.htm).

**Solution 3**

Roll your own C++ Win32 App:

```
PROCESS_INFORMATION procInfo = {0};
STARTUPINFOstartupInfo = {0};
SECURITY_ATTRIBUTESsaAttr = {0};
HANDLEhStdIn = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
HANDLEhStdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
HANDLEhStdErr = GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE);

// build up security attributes
saAttr.nLength = sizeof(saAttr);
    saAttr.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
    saAttr.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;

// set file handles for process to be created
startupInfo.cb = sizeof(startupInfo);
startupInfo.dwFlags = STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
startupInfo.hStdInput = hStdIn;
startupInfo.hStdOutput = hStdOut;
startupInfo.hStdError = hStdErr;

// build command line: format is  [cmd.exe /c "%batchScript%" %batchArgs%]
if (-1 == _snprintf_s(cmd, sizeof(cmd),"cmd.exe /c \"%s\" %s", batchScript, batchArgs))
errorExit("_snprintf_s(\"cmd.exe /c \"%%s\" %%s\"), \"%s\", \"%s\") failed.", batchScript, batchArgs);

rc = CreateProcess(NULL, cmd, NULL, &saAttr, TRUE, CREATE_NO_WINDOW, NULL, tempPath, &startupInfo, &procInfo);
```

Comment: The build-time [linker config](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fcc1zstk.aspx) is what determines whether or not an application is given a console window by Windows.  I appreciate the suggestions, but none of these really solve my problem.  If node is built with the correct linker option, the console window won't be created in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the SubSystem field value in node.exe PE optional header. The current value is 3 which is defined as Windows Console. If you change it to 2 (which is defined as Windows GUI) there would be no console window. In order to patch the executable file, you have to use utilities to change Optional Header of PE.
One example of such a tool is [PE tools](https://github.com/petoolse/petools).

[image]

Click on Optinal Header and then change the Subsystem from 3 to 2.
[image]

That`s all.

Remember that with this change you can only run js files. You can not use interactive mode.