# How do I run a windows task without flashing a command prompt box BUT still show a dialog box when I need to?

Tags: windows, node.js, scheduled-tasks, task

I creating a scheduled task in windows using windows command prompt:

```
schtasks /create /sc minute /mo 30 /tn "javadobe" /tr "\Program Files (x86)\BuildingIntelligence\javadobe\node.exe '\Program Files (x86)\BuildingIntelligence\javadobe\index.js'" /RL HIGHEST
```

Which is telling the command line to run "node index.js" every 30 minutes with the highest running privileges.

In my index.js file, I am checking a remote server for a version number I compare against a local version number.  Now when they are the same, a node prompt window flashes briefly on the screen, which is obnoxious, and I would like to stop.
However, when the host server uploads a new version of the software, I show a dialog box asking the user if they want to install the update now or later.  I want to keep this functionality.

How can I keep the dialog box popping up but not show the node.js command prompt flashing all the time?

**Things I have tried:**

1. I have tried running my script as a service instead of a scheduled task, which keeps the windows command prompt from appearing, but doesn't allow the dialog box to appear to the user (because services run in a different desktop session).
2. In normal windows command prompt, you can start a program minimized, using

   START /MIN [application name]

   and so I tried changing my /tr argument to "start node index.js /MIN" but that didn't work.

Thanks a bunch in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Whether or not Windows creates a console window for an application is controlled by the [Windows Subsystem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fcc1zstk.aspx) specified in the binary image (exe file) — something specified at compile time.

If this is `CONSOLE` (as node.js is), Windows creates the console window *before* the application begins executing.  In other words, it is impossible to control at runtime whether or not a window appears.  If `WINDOWS`, Windows does not create a console window, as it expects the application to create UI.

You will have to [create a custom build of the node.js executable with subsystem `WINDOWS`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22653825/201952).